# Does the geometry of a lever alter the behavior of rotation

Tags: rotational-dynamics, geometry

Here is a simplified example

[image]

If we consider that both A and B are the same body which is only free to rotate, F is the force acting at the exact same distance from that body in both cases, with the same magnitude and over the same period of time, will the body end up in the same ending position in both cases?

In other words does the geometry of the lever play any role?

Edit:
I forgot to mention, that we should also consider the lever to be weightless, as if it is not it will move the center of mass and the question is not regarding that, but purely dynamics of rotation.

Comment: Where is the fulcrum of the levers, i.e. the point about which it pivots?

Comment: @Not_Einstein the points A and B, which were supposed to be single points but I drew them a little too big so I called them bodies, essentially their centers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They should get displaced by same angle, as the torque equations would be same in both cases.

Comment: The torque is the same but don't they have different moments of inertia?

Comment: Question assumes the levers to be massless

Comment: I missed that, thanks. But then we have Torque = 0 x Angular Acceleration ?

Comment: Tis is an idealized case .A   torque ,in negative to the torque we give,  needs to be  at hinge point.

Comment: Other wise it would be like pulling a massless block with a massless string

Comment: Also A &B ARE BODIES, they have inertia

Comment: Yes I probably didn't do a very good job of explaining what I wanted to know, good thing @Protein understood me.

Comment: I'm still wondering about this. A & B are not moving, they are fulcrum points. And being at the fulcrum, they do not contribute torque. In the limit as the mass of the levers -> 0, an applied torque will produce an angular acceleration that -> infinity. So to be realistic we consider some mass to the levers. But then the moment of inertia of the B lever about the fulcrum point is larger than the moment about A, hence results in different motion.

Comment: @Not_Einstein I'm designing a steering mechanism and I've calculated the angle at which my steering arm (or whatever it is called) should stay. The problem is that when it goes out straight it can not complete the 40 degrees of rotation needed because it hits what would be my lower control arm (don't ask how). In order to achieve my full motion I would need to bend the arm and I was wondering if that would still keep my proper "ackerman steering". That's why angular velocity and moment of inertia don't matter, although I might have asked the question as if they would.